# Dynamic menu button items in TinyMCE

Tags: dynamic, tinymce, refresh

I have a custom menubutton in my tinyMCE editor that uses specific HTML elements elsewhere on the page as the menu items. I use a jQuery selector to get the list of elements and then add one each as a menu item:

```
c.onRenderMenu.add(function(c,m) {
  m.add({ title: 'Pick One:', 'class': 'mceMenuItemTitle' }).setDisabled(1);
  $('span[data-menuitem]').each(function() {
    var val = $(this).html();
    m.add({ 
      title: $(this).attr("data-menuitem"), 
      onclick: function () { tinyMCE.activeEditor.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, val) }
    });
  });
});
```

My problem is that this only happens once when the button is first clicked and the menu is first rendered. The HTML elements on the current page will change occasionally based on user clicks and some AJAX, so I need this selector code to run each time the menu is rendered to make sure the menu is fully up-to-date. Is that possible?

Failing that, is it possible to dynamically update the control from the end of my AJAX call elsewhere in the page? I'm not sure how to access the menu item and to update it. Something using `tinyMCE.activeEditor.controlManager`...?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution to this problem, though I'm not sure it's the best path.

It doesn't look like I can make tinyMCE re-render the menu, so instead I've added some code at the end of my AJAX call: after it has updated the DOM then it manually updates the tinymce drop menu.

The menu object is accessible using:

```
tinyMCE.activeEditor.controlManager.get('editor_mybutton_menu')
```

where *mybutton* is the name of my custom control. My quick-and-dirty solution is to call `removeAll()` on this menu object (to remove all the current menu items) and then to re-execute my selector code to find the matching elements in the (new) DOM and to add the menu items back based on the new state.

It seems to work just fine, though tweaks & ideas are always welcome!